# Problems quering/deserializing multilevel field objects

Tags: socrata, soda

https://opendata.miamidade.gov/Corrections/Jail-Bookings-May-29-2015-to-current/7nhc-4yqn?

I don't if someone could help me with this: I've been having problems parsing/de-serializing the Address information that comes inside the Location object.

This is a fragment of the code i am using:

```
var results = dataset.Query<MiamiDade_JailLog>(soql);

public class MiamiDade_JailLog
{
    public string chargecode3 { get; set; }
    public string charge2 { get; set; }
    public string bookdate { get; set; }
    public string charge3 { get; set; }
    public string chargecode1 { get; set; }
    public string chargecode2 { get; set; }
    public string charge1 { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public Location1 location_1 { get; set; }
    public string defendant { get; set; }
}

public class Location1
{
    public bool needs_recoding { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public HumanAddress human_address { get; set; }
}

public class HumanAddress
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the error message:

> Error converting value
>   `"{"address":"HOMELESS","city":"MIAMI","state":"FL","zip":""}"` to type
>   'JailLog_WFA.HumanAddress'. Path 'location_1.human_address', line 1,
>   position 424.

Comment: any reason you are using your own `Location` and `HumanAddress` types? The `SODA.NET` library (which I assume you are also using) has these classes defined under `SODA.Models`. Have you tried using them?

Answer (score 0):

This is the response I got from Socrata:
If you look at this json response, https://opendata.miamidade.gov/resource/7nhc-4yqn.json 
You'll see that for the `location_1` column, we provide an object, `{}` 
and then within there you'll see `human_address` which we provide as a string `""` instead of as an object. 
For JavaScript, it would just be `JSON.parse("{\"address\":\"17725 NW 8TH PL\",\"city\":\"MIAMI GARDENS\",\"state\":\"FL\",\"zip\":\"33169\"}");` 
From the code you sent, it looks like you are treating HumanAddress as an object instead of as a string that needs to be parsed into an object. 
If you make this change it should work.

...And this was my response:
You gave me very good info. However I had already done a workaround to parse the object. 
I just removed the extra quotes from the human_ address object and was able to parse everything at once.